# Goop under carpet padding

Tags: flooring, floor, cleaning

We're pulling up carpet in a new-to-us house. There's a beautiful hardwood floor underneath that is in great shape except that there's some red/brown sticky goop spots left behind by the carpet padding. The padding is that multi-colored stuff and it seems like the red parts have melted or something. We don't know how long the carpet has been there, but it doesn't look like it's been there more than ten years. Under the goop, the floor finish is fine. I'd love to clean this stuff off and not have to completely refinish the floors.

The red stuff is still tacky. We can scrape most of it up, but it leaves behind a red film. What do you think we could use to clean this stuff up?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an orange oil product like Goo-Gone to try to remove the remaining sticky film. Apply directly to the spots, let sit for a short time and the use clean paper towels to wipe up the mess.

Comment: I have used orange oil on concrete to remove adhesive from vinyl tile. I used a "putty knife" with a dull edge to scrape up the softened adhesive. Wipe off the knife on newspaper to prepare the putty knife for the next scrape.

Comment: I ended up using Orange Goop hand cleaner last night based on another post and it worked well. The orange oil plus a bit of grit really worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would scrape up the bulk of it and then use Zep Citrus degreaser on what's left. It will be lest expense that Goo-Gone. You can try a spray bottle of it and if you need a lot, get a gallon of it. https://www.homedepot.com/p/ZEP-128-oz-Heavy-Duty-Citrus-Degreaser-ZUCIT128/100676344

Comment: I ended up using Orange Goop hand cleaner last night based on another post and it worked well. The orange oil plus a bit of grit really worked. It was about $10 a gallon so I got two. I have a LOT left over. Enough to wash my hands for years.